# php version in cpanel is 5.6 but show version 7 in project

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a codeigniter project  that is live and when i check php version in cpanel cli for the domain of project it shows 5.6 but if i do

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

It gives PHP Version 7.4.29

I want it to be php 5.6 I have tried changing it from php multi manager in cpanel

Comment: CLI, and PHP embedded in the web server, often use different configurations.

Comment: PHP CLI is different from PHP used for web.

Comment: Then what is solution as I am using encrypt library which isn't functioning because of Php version

Comment: @MohammadFahadRao You might want to post that as a new question.

Comment: It should be configurable in the cPanel settings. If you can't figure it out, contact your hosting company for support. Possibly though they don't allow PHP 5.6 because it has been unsupported for several years. Time for you to upgrade.